# Php echo highest number from Json

Tags: php, numbers, echo, highest

I'm searching an external Json page, for $a and echoing $b.

```
<?php
$jsonurl = "site.com/json.json";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$json_output = json_decode($json);

foreach ($json_output as $page) {
    foreach($page->X as $X) {
        if (isset($X->a)) {
            $a= $x->a;
            $b  = $x->b;
    if ( $a == 'Hello' || $a == 'Hi'){
    echo $b
```

$b is a number, and there could be only one number or perhaps two or three. If there's more than one, what is a tidy way of only echoing the largest value of $b rather than all of them should more than one value exist?

The numbers are unknown so I can't use echo max or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$number = array();
foreach ($json_output as $page) {
    foreach($page->X as $X) {
        if (isset($X->a)) {
            $a= $x->a;
            $b  = $x->b;
            if ( $a == 'Hello' || $a == 'Hi'){
                $numbers[] = $b;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo max($numbers);
```

See [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/function.max.php)

Comment: Sorry, I should of clarified that $b is not an array.

Comment: @Leviathan How could be $b then more than one number, are they seperated with , or so? Well, give an example for $b

Comment: It's being called from $jsonurl = "site.com/json" there might be two instances of $a, every $a has a $b, every $b is a number, I only need the highest number.

Comment: @Leviathan so you do a json_decode on it? can you add an example json code in your answer?

Comment: Yes,I will edit my question to make it more clear. Sorry for the confusion.